# Layering Images and Text

Tags: html, css, centering

I am having trouble layering the images circle and line with the actual text. My goal is to have all of the elements lined up in the center of the page. Should I use a table to float? What the best method?

[Currently looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UIVN8.png)

[Goal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YGTWT.png)

**HTML**

```
<div id="two">
    <img src="line.png" id="line">
    <img src="circle.png" id="circle">
  <ul>
      <li> Photography </li>
      <li> Computer Shortcut </li>
      <li> Skiiing </li>
      <li> Podcasts </li>
      <li> Road Biking </li>
      <li> Quality </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#two{
  background-color: #D6E6F4;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
}
#circle{
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  justify-content: center;
}
#line{
  position: relative;
  top:5px;
}

#two ul{
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  list-style-type: none;
}
#two li{
  font-family: AvenirNext-Regular;
  font-size: 32px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  line-height: 26px;
  background: #B55252;
  border-radius: 8px;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 15px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Requesting two images from the server? No need if those graphic elements can be achieved using CSS (and i.e: `:before` pseudo elements).

```css
#two{
  background:#D6E6F4;
  padding-bottom:20px;
}
#two ul{
  font:13px/1.3 sans-serif;
  list-style:none;
  padding:0;
  text-align:center;
  overflow:hidden;
}
#two span{
  position:relative;
  display:inline-block;
  text-decoration:none;
  padding:5px 10px;
  background:#B25350;
  color:#fff;
  margin-top:20px;
  border-radius:5px;
}
#two li:first-of-type span{ /* THE FIRST "CIRCLE" */
  border-radius:50%;
  background:#B25350;
  width:26px;
  height:26px;
  padding:0;
}
#two li:first-of-type span:before{ /* THE "VERTICAL JOINING LINE" */
  content:"";
  background:#B25350;
  position:absolute;
  top:5px;
  height:400px;
  width:5px;
  left:50%;
  margin-left:-3px;
}
```

```html
<div id="two">
  <ul>
    <li><span></span></li>
    <li><span>Photography</span>
    <li><span>Computer Shortcut</span>
    <li><span>Skiing</span>
    <li><span>Podcasts</span>
    <li><span>Road Biking</span>
    <li><span>Quality</span>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: what does the "" next to content under #two li:last-of-type a: before? and why did you use a link, href, in the HTML?

Comment: @TannerLarson 1. well... if you use `:before` of `:after` pseudo elements, to make it "visible" on page you need to add `content:"";` Have you tried to remove `content:"";` and see what happens? 2. I've used anchor `<a>` elements so that you can make them clickable > since I supposed you need a navigation menu or sort of.

Comment: The text is centered, but the line in the background isn't showing up now and I tried deleting the content:"";

Comment: The link worked fine, but it still won't show the line or circle. Does it have something to do with it being a div with other elements on the page?

Comment: @TannerLarson Ohh, ok, in your specific case the vertical line is not appearign due to `z-index:-1;` (the line goes underneath the blue background of parent ) this has to be handled differently.

Comment: Oh okay what's the best way?

Comment: @TannerLarson if you don't want to use `a` elements, use `<span>` instead; and in CSS, instead of `a` use `span`

Comment: a small oval (not a circle) is centered at the very top of that section now, but still no line

Comment: @TannerLarson can you see the `a` selector in CSS? Can you see it in HTML? ...if you only changed the `a` selector to `span` as I've said you, it would work.

Comment: corrected the span issue, still nothing with the background. If I turn off the background the line is there.  https://jsbin.com/hopedotufe/1/edit?html,css

Comment: @TannerLarson that's NOT the CSS code from my answer. Please.... please. 1. Use the exact CSS and HTML from my answer. 2. change in HTML and everywhere in CSS `a` to `span`. Should not be that difficult.

Comment: @TannerLarson Edited again my answer, replaced `a` with `spans` - now all you really have to do is to copy-paste all into your page.

Comment: That worked thank you! Sorry about the confusion, thought you were referring the link you sent for updated CSS not the actual answer.

Comment: @TannerLarson PS: instead of  `top:0;` use `top:3px;` .. to remove the hard 5px edge from the first circle (unnoticeable small detail... just in case)